# How to maintain different version JSON document in cosmos db when PK is id and UK is id and version

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a JSON document with two properties `deviceIdentity, version`.

Partition Key for my collection is `deviceIdentity`.

My JSON documents comes with different versions I want to keep all versions of this document.

Like:

```
deviceIdentity1, v1
deviceIdentity1, v2
```

Two documents should be there.

Problem is since my PK is `deviceIdentity`, it is always updating the existing record even though I have defined a unique key constraint on `deviceIdentity`, `version`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltS4g.png)

Any pointers will be of help!

Comment: You meant id of the document is deviceIdentity and may be it has the same partitionke too. Am I right? You can have multiple documents with same partitionkey, but only one document for id. May be one option can be to add version to the id also.

Comment: I have a different property named as "id", Partitioning is on "deviceIdentity".

We are getting this document from a source, do you mean while inserting the document in Cosmos Db we manipulate the id value and append version value to it?

Comment: agree with @RafatSarosh, adding version to id should solve the issue

Comment: btw, if you have deviceIdentity as a partitionKey, no  needs to add the same as  document id. you can use version field for that purposes

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confusing `partition key` with `primary key`.

**Partition key** determines how data is scaled horizontally. This should not be unique as otherwise any read except exact document lookup would require to scan all partitions, which would be innefficient. In your case `deviceIdentity` may be a suitable candidate - all versions of the same device would fall to same partition.

**Primary key** is your document identity (the field `id`). As you already noticed, there can be only 1 document with given `id`. The `id` field MUST be unique per document you want to store. In your case, you could use a combination values like `"deviceIdentity1, v2"` as the identity. Or, you could use technical unique id, like a guid.

Also, note that by [Unique keys in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys):

> By creating a unique key policy when a container is created, you ensure the uniqueness of one or more values **per partition key**.

Meaning if your partition key is `deviceIdentity` then you don't have to duplicate the `deviceIdentity` in unique constraint part. Constraint on `/version` would suffice to ensure that every single partition/device has at most one document per version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers.

The problem was we have an old legacy system where “id “was an already heavily used property but it did not have unique values.

So whenever a document comes with a different version it was updating as “id” in cosmos has predefined meaning that is UPSERT of any arriving document is done on unique id value, in our case id is never unique.

Solution we found.

Whenever a document comes we process it in an azure function and swap “id” column with the value of unique “deviceidentity” value and save it, as structure of JSON cannot be changed as stated by our client and while reading these documents we have exposed an API which does the swapping again and sends the document to the requesting client as it is.